# Cannot fix Unidentified index

Tags: php

So my problem is really annoying. I have a form and I am assigning a variable to my input:

```
$rememberMe = $_POST['rememberMe'];
```

Every time the remember me is not checked, I get this error and I can't figure out a way to stop this. I looked into lots of topics around the stackoverflow, but all these fix do not seem to work. I don't know why. I tripled-check my variables and they are perfect, just don't know why it shows this error!

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `$rememberMe = isset($_POST['rememberMe'])?true:false;`

Comment: You must not have done much research at all, this's gets asked a lot. Daves answer will sort it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it work.

```
 $rememberMe = isset($_POST['rememberMe'])?true:false;
```

OR to make it supper clear

```
 if(isset($_POST['rememberMe'])){
    $rememberMe = $_POST['rememberMe']; 
 } 
 else
    $rememberMe = null;  // you can put false instead of null according to your situation
```

Comment: voting it as best answer will be great favour, Thanks for you appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the notice error this way:

```
 if (isset($_POST['rememberMe'])) {
     // the key 'rememberMe' is a valid key of the array $_POST 
     $rememberMe = $_POST['rememberMe'];
 } else {
     $rememberMe = false; // or null or whatever value that suits you most
 }
```

or a little shorter approach is to use so called ternary operator:

```
$rememberMe = isset($_POST['rememberMe']) ? $_POST['rememberMe'] : false;
```

**Note:** If you use `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables, I recommend to use one of previous approaches at beginnings of your scripts and never use `$_GET['something']` in your script twice. It helps a lot to avoid problems and make your code testable.

Answer (score 0):

you should check whether  `$_POST['rememberMe']` exists

```
$rememberMe = isset($_POST['rememberMe'])?$_POST['rememberMe']:false;
```

and also you may need to check the front form whether the `checkbox` is posted and its `name` is `rememberMe` (not `id`)